# how to set highchart x-axis to display more dates and change date format

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, highcharts

currently i did a code to view graph with dynamic dates on x-axis with code:

```html
  public function graphheheByDate(Request $request, $companyID)
  {
    $companyID = $this->decode($companyID);
    
    $matchs = DiraChatLog::whereBetween('date_access', [$request->from, $request->to])->orderBy('date_access', 'asc')->get();
    foreach ($matchs as $key => $match) {
      $time = strtotime($match->date_access); 
      $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
      $a[$newformat] = $this->testing($newformat,$match);
    }

    $user = array_values($a);
    $dates = array_keys($a);
    // dd($user, $dates);

    $from = $request->from;
    $to = $request->to;
    // dd($from, $to);

    $companyID = $this->encodeID($companyID);

    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graphhehe', compact('companyID','from','to', 'dates'))->with('user',json_encode($user,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))->with('dates',json_encode($dates,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));     
  }
  
  
  
  private function testing($date,$match){
    // dd($match->date_access,$date);
    // dd($date);
    $a = Carbon::parse($date)->addDay()->toDateTimeString();
    // dd($a,$date);

    $noOfUsers = DiraChatLog::whereBetween('date_access', [$date,$a])->get();
    // dd($noOfUsers);

     return $noOfUsers->groupBy('user_id')->count();
  }
```

and in my views the highcharts script is as below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

  var date = <?php echo $dates; ?>;

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Unique Visitors'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: date,
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            align: 'right'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total'
        }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Users',
        data: {{$user ?? ''}}
    }]
});

</script>
```

currently, I have 2 problems that need to be solved. the first one which I think should be easy to change the date format to dd/mm/YYYY.

number 2 currently if I select whereBetweeen more than 10 days it only shows me the data for the first 10.. and not more than the 10. how can I make it show more than 10 values??

Comment: I see that you're using **categories** for dates on xAxis. Highcharts provides a dedicated mechanism for managing that: `datetime` type of axis (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes). When you use `datetime` axis it's easy to manipulate the format of the labels: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats